# Trying to truncate strings with Django built-in filters

Tags: django

I'd like to find a way to replace a part of a string: I'd like to remove everything after a substring, like ",".

**Example**: If my input string is `"Hello, world!"`, the output should be `"Hello"`.

I was surprised to find a `join` filter and not a `split` one.

Do I need to write a custom filter or can I do it with a built-in filter (I can't find it)?
Thank you.

Comment: Check out https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/211/

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317537/django-templates-split-string-to-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your links, I created a custom template tag myself, it perfectly works, here is the code:

// In a custom template file (see [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/))

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def del_after_char(input_str, char):
    try:
        return input_str.split(char)[0]
    except: # Do nothin if an error occurs
        return input_str
```