# how to split the string in django template?

Tags: python, django-templates, django-filter, django-1.5

i am trying to split the string in template using custom template filter. But i got an error

```
    TemplateSyntaxError at /job/16/
'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y': for skill in form.instance.skills | split : ","
```

Here it is my filter

```
@register.filter(name='split')
def split(value, key):
    """
        Returns the value turned into a list.
    """
    return value.split(key)
```

this is my template

```
<h4>Skills</h4>
{% for skill in form.instance.skills | split : "," %}
    {{ skill }}
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317537/django-templates-split-string-to-array/8318915

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Split is a custom filter, don't forget to create your filter, and to load it in your HTML page.
Documentation for Django 4.0: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-template-tags/

```
<h4>Skills</h4>
{% with form.instance.skills|split:"," as skills %}
    {% for skill in skills %}
        {{ skill }}<br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: It doesn't work due to error `Invalid filter: 'split'`. Another solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8318915/5494506.

Comment: Hum.. did you create the filter in your code? Because split is a custom filter.

Answer (score 3):

For extract character string, use filter cut:

```
<a href="tel://+1{{ phone|cut:'-' }}">Phone</a>
```

this removes the scripts from the string.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking around for how to use split filter in Django and i had difficulty to know how to create and register a filter. I tried many solutions till I was able to create a split filter, I am posting here how to do it

In views.py

```
from django.template.defaulttags import register

@register.filter(name='split')
def split(value, key): 
 
    value.split("key")
    return value.split(key)
```

and then use it in your HTML as mentioned in the previous very good answers

Hope this helps

reference: https://gist.github.com/linuxkathirvel/8127c40fdad028bbb79bec24f36eee1c

Answer (score -1):

The direct for loop works too, you just have to remove the spaces in the syntax:

```
    <h4>Skills</h4>
            {% for skill in form.instance.skills|split:"," %}
                {{ skill }}
              {% endfor %}
```