# Using split in a django template

Tags: python, django

I have a dictionary passed to an html django template:

```
return render_to_response('showdata.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request, {'dictdati': context} ))
```

this dictionary has this structure:

```
{0: 'TO;DEC;1;2012/02/28 15:39:06.000;TO;1234;SI;DI;1234;TO;1\n', 1: 'TO;DEC;1;2012/02/28 15:39:06.000;TO;567;SI;DI;567;TO;1\n'}
```

and in an html template I need to print some of the values in the each row of the dict. If in a python file I use

```
for key,val in dictdati.items():
    print val.split(';')[0]
```

it prints the first value correctly (TO) but in an html template

```
{% for key,val in dictdati.items %}
  {{ val.split[0] }}
{% endfor %}
```

in the browser I receive the error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /getdata/
Could not parse the remainder: '[0]' from 'val.split[0]'
```

Can someone give me an idea to solve this problem?

Comment: [Add a custom template filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41932634/how-to-split-the-string-in-django-template), it's very simple and you can use it later.

Answer (score 0):

you cant just call arbitrary logic in django... this is probably more of a job for the backend if you only want 0th but i think you can use the `first` filter

```
{{ my_var.split | first }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found solution so I made a custom Django filter

The Custom filter code:

```py
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_index(value, arg):
    return value[int(arg)]
```

And the HTML code:

```html
{% for key,val in dict.items %}
    {{ val|get_index:"0" }}
{% endfor %}
```

In get_index give the index number needed
Also, I see you have used string and then commas as values I have used it as a list so this code only works for value as list