# How to perform split() function inside django template tag?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I need to perform split() function inside django template tag.
I tried to do this, but its not working

```
{% for m in us.member %}
    {% with mv=((m.split(','))[0].split('='))[1] %}
           <h3 class="media-title">
                {{ mv }}
           </h3>
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

Here value of m return a string value

> 'cn=RND3,ou=Production_test,dc=iss,dc=rndtest,dc=local'

Expected output is RND3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to split the string in django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41932634/how-to-split-the-string-in-django-template)

Comment: no, it could handled this problem

Answer (score 0):

> It is not possible to run a raw python code inside the templates in
>   django.

But then alternatevekly you can create custom template tag which can fulfill your requrement. More you can read here in the offical docs of [django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/)

I hope this helps....Thanks :)