# Django template split a string in two parts

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In my Django project i hae to split a string into a template based on a specific char.

```
str1 = "Part1 - Part2"
```

in pure python I would do it like this:

```
part1 = str1.split("-",1)[0]
part2 = str1.split("-",1)[1]
```

using django template instead i try:

```
{{ str1|split:'-'|first }}
```

but i give an error:

> Invalid filter: 'split'

Someone can help me for split my variable ina django template and take just the first or second part based on a specific char?

So many thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django templates - split string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317537/django-templates-split-string-to-array)

Comment: I guess there is no split tag in Django. You will need to implement it yourself. I've found this solution https://moonbooks.org/Articles/How-to-create-a-list-of-items-from-a-string-in-a-Django-template-/

Comment: mmm sorry but i don't understand how resolve my problem based on that link. thanks

Comment: Does this stackoverflow question- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317537/django-templates-split-string-to-array answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to split the string in django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41932634/how-to-split-the-string-in-django-template)

Comment: You can implement your own split filter in django. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/ here's the official docs to implement custom template tags

Answer (score 3):

using `templatetags` split would be something like this:

as `templatetags` only takes `one argument`, but for split with max limit we need to pass `two arguments`.
in such case we can combind the two arguments as a string and use a separator.
here for example i'm using `||||` as two arguments separator

in your app folder create one folder, named `templatetags`

there create a file `split.py` :

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def split(splitable, split_at):
    # split with max limit
    if len(split_at.split("||||")) == 2:
        return splitable.split(split_at.split("||||")[0], int(split_at.split("||||")[1]))
    
    # normal split without max limitation
    return splitable.split(split_at)
```

now it's better to restart your server once.

then in template do:

```
{% load split %}

<!-- first element no split limit -->
{{ str1|split:"-"|first }}

<!-- first element with split limit, in following example, the limit is 1 -->
{{ str1|split:"-||||1"|first }}

<!-- last element no split limit -->
{{ str1|split:"-"|last }}

<!-- last element with split limit, in following example, the limit is 1 -->
{{ str1|split:"-||||1"|last }}

<!-- element by index no split limit -->
{% with str1|split:"-" as split_data %}{{ split_data.0 }}{% endwith %}

<!-- element by index with split limit, in following example, the limit is 1 -->
{% with str1|split:"-||||1" as split_data %}{{ split_data.0 }}{% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Your Template you need to directly use the converted value because there is no way filter to split text in templates

```html
{{ part1 }} {{ part2 }}
```