# Looping through CSV string in Django Template

Tags: html, django, django-templates

So I have a variable that is a comma separated string ("val1,val2,val3") and I want to iterate through each element in a Django template like:

```
{% for host in network.hosts %}
<h3>{{host}}</h3>
{% endfor %}
```

In this case my csv variable is network.hosts and my expected result would be:

val1

val2

val3

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django templates - split string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317537/django-templates-split-string-to-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a custom template tag and use it. Use following code to create a new template tag for your work done.

```
@register.filter(name='split')
def split(value, arg):
    return value.split(arg)
```

Then you can use this filter in your template like following code.

```
{% with network.hosts|split:"," as hosts_list %}
    {% for host in hosts_list %}
     <h3>{{host}}</h3>
    {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

Django official site will help you on creating custom template tags https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: its giving me an error, seems to not like 'split',  Django Version: 1.11.2
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value: 
Invalid filter: 'split'

Answer (score 0):

One way of getting this to work is by defining a model in your that would allow you to split the string.

In your Python code, you could add this function to your model:

```
class Networks(models.Model):
    ...
    def hosts_as_list(self):
        return self.hosts.split(',')
```

Then your template could look like:

```
{% for host in network.hosts.hosts_as_list %}
    {{ host }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Hope it helps!

Source - [Django templates - split string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317537/django-templates-split-string-to-array)