# Displaying only the first paragraph of a body of text in a Django template

Tags: python, django, text, paragraph

If I have a large body of text, e.g. a blog post, how could I display the entire first paragraph of each text on the blog's home page, instead of breaking it on a random letter in a random word with the following?

```
  <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr|slice:":400" }}</p>
```

Comment: Define a paragraph

Comment: Looking through the built-in filters, the closest fit for this situation is [truncatewords](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatewords), which at least splits it at the end of a word. For more complex rules than that, you will have to define your own filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try avoiding this type of operations in your templates, they are not designed for that. Instead, implement that functionality in your `models.py` or `views.py` with the appropriate `split('\n')`

Have a look at [Django templates - split string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317537/django-templates-split-string-to-array).