# Why won't Django template recognize list from object field?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have an object field that stores a list.  The Django template is treating the list like a string, it iterates over each character, not each list value.

Tried saving the object field in various ways, "['1','2']" and "1,2".  Tried the "|make_list" filter.

models.py

```
class SpecialField(models.Model):
    name =  models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)
    description =  models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)
    value_options = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)
    # value_options might be "['1','2']" or "red, green, blue"
```

views.py

```
object_field_list= SpecialField.objects.all()

context = {
    'object_field_list': object_field_list,
}

return render(request, 'app1/template-detail.html', context)
```

template

```
{% for object_field in object_field_list%}

    {% for list_value in object_field.value_options %}
       <option>{{ list_value }}</option>
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

I was hoping for:

```
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
```

But I am getting:

```
<option>[</option>
<option>'</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>'</option>
<option>,</option>
<option>'</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>'</option>
<option>]</option>
```

Comment: You must be passing this as a string

Comment: @HenryM I think you are correct.  Do you know how to pass it as list?

Comment: show how you've passed it

Comment: You need to show us what `object_field` is.

Comment: Thank you, I've added more detail to the original post so you can see how I am passing the data to the template from the view

Comment: you still haven't shown how object_field_list is created

Comment: @henryM - just added the QuerySet for you

Comment: What does your model definition look like? You're thinking you are looping over a field on `SpecialField` but you actually have a queryset of objects as best I can tell.

Comment: @tom -- added the model for you, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are wanting to show data from a model, so let's suppose you have a model

```
class SpecialField(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=101)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Given the way you've set in in `context` you can show this in the template with

```
{% for obj in object_field_list %}
    {{ obj.name}} - {{ obj.price }}
{% endfor %}
```

Obviously, you need to amend for your model

---

Tweak on your suggestion...it needs one more level of looping.  Still can't get it to work.

models.py

```
class SpecialField(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=101)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    custom_list = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

template

```
{% for obj in object_field_list %}
    {{ obj.name}} - {{ obj.price }}

    {% for list_value in obj.custom_list %}
        {{ list_value }}
        # this is where it's breaking for me
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
context = {
    'object_field_list': SpecialField.objects.values_list('value_options', flat=True),
}
```

Should get you what you actually want to loop over.

EDIT: Sorry, I missed the fact you are storing a string rather than using an `ArrayField` or similar. The problem from your updated answer is the data you have isn't consistent. If it were simply all comma-separated values you could do:

```
object_field_list = [value_list.split(',') for value_list in SpecialField.objects.values_list('value_options', flat=True)]
```

but you will need some way of normalizing the data you're storing in `value_options`. How does the data get into the database? If it's via Django, you can apply some kind of cleaning method on the form or API endpoint that accepts the data.

> Tried saving the object field in various ways, "['1','2']" and "1,2". Tried the "|make_list" filter.

If you have complete control over the incoming data, you would be better off [normalizing the data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization): rather than storing a single `value_options` entry on `SpecialField`, you would remove that field and add a second model, e.g., `SpecialFieldOption` like

```py
class SpecialFieldOption(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    field = models.ForeignKey(SpecialField, related_name='options')

# now you can do

SpecialField.objects.get(pk=1).options.all()
```

to loop over the list of all options for a given `SpecialField`.

Comment: Thanks Tom, but not sure that will do it.  It's almost like there is a list of lists, your suggestion will only take care of the outer list.

Answer (score 0):

This was the handiest solution...define a new list using split.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8318915/9268133.  Thanks for everyone's help!