# Split a string in django template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I am storing tags as a string seprated by commas in a model and i am trying to print those in template but it is not working I tried [Django templates - split string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317537/django-templates-split-string-to-array/8317586) answer but it is also not working nothing is printed and the function tags_as_list is also not running

model

```
class News(models.Model):
 link = models.TextField()
 headline = models.TextField()
 summary = models.TextField()
 tags = models.TextField(blank=True)
 time_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def tags_as_list(self):
    print("tagsss")
    return self.tags.split(',')
```

template

```
{% for tag in news_item.tags.tags_as_list %}
{{ tag }}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `tags_as_list` you defined is correct, however in the template you are not calling it correctly.

Assuming `news_item` is an instance of `News` you should call `news_item.tags_as_list` as the method is not on the `tags`, but on the model.

Answer (score 0):

I was not using the function properly it directly gets access to the feild you don't have to mention it by yourself

```
{% for tag in news_item.tags_as_list %}
{{ tag }}
{% endfor %}
```